# How to do a model function inside jquery append

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, append

Good Afternoon all,

I have a ajax request that goes to the controller, after that on the success its supposed to create a card with the car properties.

My ajax success and append:

```
 success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.data)
                $('#div_viaturas').html("");
                $.each(data.data, function(k, v) {
                    $('#div_viaturas').append('<div class="col-md-3 p-2 card">'
                        +'<div class="card_pic" alt="volvo" style="background-image: url(https://cld.pt/dl/download/bab2c1e8-4b1a-4b0f-8419-31d331543081/Fotos/{{v.numero_viatura}}/{{(new \App\Fotos)->getFotoDestacadaViatura(v.id)}})"></div>'
                        +'<div class="card_info">'
                        +'<div class="form-group row no-gutters">'
                        +(v.tipo_id = 1 ?  '<p class="col-9 card_cat" style="text-align: left;">Tractor</p>' : ' <p class="col-9 card_cat"' + 'style="text-align: left;">(new \App\Sub_tipos)->getSubCategoriasById(v.sub_tipo_id)</p>')
                        +'<p class="col-3 card_year" style="text-align: right;">' + v.ano + '</p> </div>' +
                        ' <div class="form-group row no-gutters">' +
                        ' <p class="col-12 card_title">'+ {{(new \App\Marcas)->getMarcasById(v.marca_id)}}   + v.modelo+'</p>' +
                        ' </div>' +
                        '<div class="form-group row no-gutters">' +
                        '                                    <p class="col-6 card_kms"' +
                        '                                       style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom;">'+ v.kilometros +
                        '                                        km</p>' +
                        '                                    <p class="col-6 card_price" style="text-align: right;">Preço S/' +
                        '                                        Consulta</p>' +
                        '                                </div>' +
                        '                            </div>' +
                        '                        </div>'
                    )
                });
            },
```

the problem is append does not accept the following line:

```
   {{(new \App\Marcas)->getMarcasById(v.marca_id)}}
```

this line goes to the model function "getMarcasById" with the parameter id and return the name of the brand.

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Since `v.marca_id` is a `JS` variable, you can't use it in a `PHP` function. Your API could save the result of that call in `PHP`, something like `$v->marcas_by_id = \App\Marcas::getMarcasById($marca_id)` and it will be accessible in `JS` like `v.marcas_by_id`, but the way you have now will not work.

Comment: The model (laravel) is in php processed on server side. JQuery and Javascript runs on client side. You cannot call functions of one script from another script.

Comment: Okay i see, thanks, so any idea how could i make this work?  marca_id is a foreign key on table viaturas(cars) of table marcas(brands). So i need to find a way that with the id returned by the controller, get the name of the brand